# Ping multiple ip addresses in parallel and output to multiple .TXT files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ip, ping, parallel.foreach, simultaneous

I want to ping continuously (ping -t) 3 differents IPs simultaneously and export the result with a timestamp in 3 different .txt file but i don't know how to ping the 3 IPs in parralel.

The script kind of work but it only create the first .txt file. I know that the first ping has to be done to go the the next one becaucause when i "ping -n 1" (only one ping), it create the 3 txt files as expected.

How can i "ping -t" the 3 IPs simultaneously and export the result in 3 different files?

my script:

```
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$IP1 = '192.168.1.1'
$IP2 = '192.168.1.2'
$IP3 = '192.168.1.3'
$IPs = $IP1,$IP2,$IP3

foreach ($IP in $IPs){
ping.exe -t $IP|Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} | Out-File "C:\PINGS\$enddate _ $IP.txt"
}
```

as a result, i would have 3 files with the ping results inside:

20190401_192.168.1.1.txt

20190401_192.168.1.2.txt

20190401_192.168.1.3.txt

I am a newbie in coding. I tried with Start-Job cmdlet to ping simultaneously but i don't get it at all.

Could you help me with this?

Thank's by advance

Comment: You were on the right track with Start-Job. Can you post your code for that? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem but the script works.
When i run the script from PowerShell ISE or from a PowerShell window with the .\scriptName.ps1 command, it create the .txt files and i see the jobs.
But when i launch the .ps1 by double clicking it, it doesn't create txt files and  there is no jobs running.
WHY ???

By the way, for my pinging script i did 2 files.

The first one start a job to another .ps1

File 1:

```
#$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$IP1 = '192.168.1.1'
$IP2 = '192.168.1.2'
$IP3 = '192.168.1.3'
$IPs = $IP1,$IP2,$IP3
$LogPath = "C:\PINGS"
foreach ($IP in $IPs){
    Start-Job C:\PINGS\PingHost.ps1 -ArgumentList $IP,$LogPath
}
```

File 2:

```
[Cmdletbinding()]

Param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
    Position = 0)]
    [String[]]$Hostnames,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
    Position = 1)]
    [String]$FilePath    
)

$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd

Foreach($hostname in $Hostnames) {
    $LogPath = $FilePath + "\$date" + "_" + "$hostname" + ".txt"
    ping.exe -t $hostname |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} | Out-File -LiteralPath $LogPath
}
```

Thank's to a friend of mine.

But he does not know why the script do not work when i execute it from double click or right-click -> open with -> powershell.